# Facebook JS SDK allow user to choose friends and send apprequest to only those who have not already authorized application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm building a facebook application and at a certain point in the app I would like to allow users to select several friends from a list of all their friends. I would then like to send an apprequest to those friends the user selected that have not already authorized the app. Is this possible with either the graph api or a SDK dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify the exlude_ids when displaying the app request dialog

Answer (score 4):

Just add filters parameter, just like below.

```
FB.ui(
    {
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'blabla',
    filters: ['app_non_users'],
}, (...)
```